# visual studio code surround with extention can not find surround.custom snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, surround

The first time I use surround with after starting vs code, I can find the surround.custom scripts that I created, as indicated in the next image
[image]
After I use one of those custom surround with scripts successful, If I try to use again one of those custom surround with scripts, vs code does not display them anymore.
[image]

To fix that, I restart vscode. So I have to restart vscode multiple times to use custom surround scripts multiple times.

That issue started a few months ago, before that I was able to use custom scripts multiple times without any issue.

I am using vscode version 1.59.0 and SURROUND extension version 1.2.2. I tried earlier versions, and faced the same issue.

Any suggestion on a fix for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, that is fixed if the following checkbox is unchecked

[image]

alternatively, settings.json file could be modified manually. The following element should be added

```
"surround.showRecentlyUsedFirst": false
```